# LTE SIB based query

Tags: lte

We knows SIBs are transmitted from BCCH down to PDSCH and we use them to configure PHY, MAC, RLC layer.

Now when UE gets to SIB so it will already have decoded PDCCH and DCI info, right.

So, can UE know where the data is? Can't it read it?

Comment: what do you mean by "data"? To decode SIB, UE needs to decode the PDCCH and DCI of the SIB. For other information, the UE needs to decode the PDCCH and DCI of the information transmission.

Comment: By data the meaning was the user data that N/W sends. I spent more time and understood that for each detail send by N/W on PDSCH the information of location of PRB will be decoded pre-hand from PDCCH & DCI and then we can proceed ahead to know the DCI Format and RNTI sent by N/W. Based on it further the type of data sent by N/W can be known.

Comment: no, this is not correct. You need to know DCI format and RNTI to monitor PDCCH search space to *blind-decode* the PDCCH that contains DCI that contains the allocation information of PDSCH (for example location of PRB). Also, what do you do mean by "N/W"?  Talking about standards, please use only the standard's abbreviations because we have too many such thing.

Comment: by "blind-decoding", which is LTE terminology, I mean searching for all possible PDCCH